# External Firebase communication to Elm via Ports?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, elm

I have custom Firebase auth processes `(Auth0 => Firebase)`, so I run all my login logic using TypeScript with Svelte, once I have a successful JWT token, either from sessionStorage or from a fresh login, I boot off my Elm app, sending it some JWT and profile info via a flag. It's a SPA, with a routeing and pages, all componentized and working fine.

My only real problem now is, when it comes to firebase, sure, ElmFire exists, but how do I just give it an active auth token etc. And without loading Firebase for JS and also ElmFire for Elm, it just seems like way too many Kb's.

Is there a nice and efficient way to let Elm port out a "hey listen to this ref", with a "hey Elm, I have some new data for you for this ref". Ports to tell JS to listen, and subscriptions to tell Elm about new data. Without having a port for every listener, and a subscription for every data callback.

Ideally, I'd like my update, to send off a CMD that accepts a callback Msg, to update the function to call and a ref. So that way I can store that in a List of some sort, and when I get a new data payload from JS, I can loop through my List to find the item that matches the ref, execute the update, send in the Msg with the string value, so decoding happens on the pages' update.

> Someone feel free to abstract this question into something more general. Feel like this question is something more people might have.

Comment: Everything you want to do can be done with ports and subscriptions. (Note that elmfire has not been updated to 0.18.)

Comment: @SimonH but is there a way to listen to multiple ref's with a single port / sub?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that port/sub must be typed in Elm.

So, a single port / sub with one argument could listen to multiple refs as long as they all have the same type.

If not, you could define the port / sub with multiple arguments, one for each type of data you want to exchange, and pass any particular data in the proper argument.  The other arguments would be null.